# Importing Ascii/Grid file with MapXtreme2008?

Tags: c#, import, mapxtreme

We are looking at upgrading to MapXtreme2008 from MapX4.5/Vertical Mapper3 with the 60 days trial version. We are not able to import Ascii/Grid file with MapXtreme. We have try posting on the MapXtreme forum, but no answer so far. Thanks.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESRI_grid

Comment: can you provide more details on the problem?

Comment: We want to import Ascii/Grid (elevation, soil type, land use) with MapXtreme. MapXtreme support raster data with .mig file.

We where able to import the data by creating a table with each cell point and then use InverseDistanceWeightedInterpolator to create the grid. It work, but it is very slow. Under 1 minute with MapX/Vertical Mapper and 18 minutes with MapXtreme. It is the creation of the table with each point that take times.

Answer (score 0):

If **Cell Width** is too long,it takes so much time to create a grid from points using an interpolator.
However,you can specify which interpolator, how to aggregate points.
Here a code example:

```
//outTable and usaCapsTable is given

// Create the Interpolator
InverseDistanceWeightedInterpolator idw = new InverseDistanceWeightedInterpolator();
// Set the values
idw.SearchRadius = 100; // in pixels
idw.Exponent = 2;
idw.MinPoints = 1;
idw.MaxPoints = 1000;

// Create a GridCreator and pass in the table to use for input, the column holding the data, the interpolator. 
MapInfo.Raster.GridCreatorFromFeatures cg = new GridCreatorFromFeatures(usaCapsTable, "Pop_1990", idw, outTable);
cg.CellWidth = new Distance(12.9, DistanceUnit.Mile);
Inflection[] infl = new Inflection[5];
infl[0] = new Inflection(8000, Color.Blue);
infl[1] = new Inflection(121000, Color.Aquamarine);
infl[2] = new Inflection(199000, Color.Green);
infl[3] = new Inflection(298000, Color.Yellow);
infl[4] = new Inflection(980000, Color.Red);

// Create a grid Style to use and pass in the onflection points.
cg.GridStyle = new GridStyle(infl, true, Color.White, true);

// Now check if there is a current selection. If yes then use the objects to clip the grid against.
if ((MapInfo.Engine.Session.Current.Selections.DefaultSelection.Count > 0) &&
    MapInfo.Engine.Session.Current.Selections.DefaultSelection[0].Count > 0)
{
    MapInfo.FeatureProcessing.FeatureProcessor fp = new MapInfo.FeatureProcessing.FeatureProcessor();
    Feature clip = fp.Combine(MapInfo.Engine.Session.Current.Selections.DefaultSelection[0]);
    cg.ClippingGeometry = clip.Geometry;
}
else
{
    cg.ClippingGeometry = null;
}

// Create the grid file.
cg.CreateGrid();
```

Hope this helps 
Myra